# Changing time units of direction window in ArcGIS network analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I want to change direction window unit from minutes to seconds . I set travel time unit to

second and the result of the direction window show second but the unit remains min .For

example in the below image, the numbers are in second but unit remains min.How can i change unit from min to sec ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the Directions tab of the Network Dataset Properties, change the "Time Attribute" field to your TravelTime parameter when it's set to seconds. Does that help?

Comment: @Maksim unfortunately not :(